# Rails routes looking for show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, conflict

I am pretty new to rails and basically I want to make a user registration form.

I am currently using rails 3.2.3

Basically I want to make basic routes like user/register on top of basic REST route for user.

Here are my routes.rb

```
resources :user do
  collection do
    get 'register'
  end
end
```

And here are my rake routes:

```
     register_user_index GET    /user/register(.:format)   user#register
     user_index GET    /user(.:format)            user#index
                POST   /user(.:format)            user#create
       new_user GET    /user/new(.:format)        user#new
      edit_user GET    /user/:id/edit(.:format)   user#edit
           user GET    /user/:id(.:format)        user#show
                PUT    /user/:id(.:format)        user#update
                DELETE /user/:id(.:format)        user#destroy
```

From my understanding, since register user is on top of show, it should match with register first before going to show.

However, when I try to do localhost:3000/user/register, it gives me this error:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user"}

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have a view for user#register yet? If so, can you post the contents?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a typo somewhere? Even if it misses the `register` route, why would it say you don't have a `show` route? It's right there! Are you having any problems with other routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I would make this a comment, but I need the markup for the code example.)

I tried your routes using Rails 3.1.4 and it worked like you expected.

I notice you are using a string instead of a symbol.  The more standard way is:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get :register
  end
end
```

Comment: And I also changed using symbol. I don't know if it make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Did you misspell you resource? It's usually plural, `users`. But that's not the point -- it's just a convention. The point is you probably created a controller called `UsersController` and this controller doesn't follow your resource name. Check it, or make it name `UserController`. But I would strongly recommend you to **not** do that -- if you need `/user` path, just use the option `:path` with your resource and you'll be fine:

```
resources :users, path: 'user' do
```

Again, if it's not too late, use just:

```
resources :users do
```

And your registration path will be `/users/register`.

Comment: Thank you! It Worked!! I think it is convention thing.